# Ordering elements in a layout file

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to layout my elements such that the button occupies the bottom of the screen and the remaining elements arranged in a successive manner at the top of the screen but with no success. The last EditExt(opedt) is always showed a bit distant from the others somewhere in the middle of the screen. What changes to have them in the desired order?
Here is my XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/beezlinkbackg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="gsie.beezlink.OpportunityActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width= "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/posterbtn"
            android:background="#008000"
            android:id="@+id/posterbtn"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinteretxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/cinteretxt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cinteretspin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/optitretxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/optitretxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretspin"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/optitreedt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optitretxt"
        android:hint="@string/hintoptitre"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/optxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/optxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optitreedt"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opedt"
        android:hint="@string/hintpost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optxt"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: It looks like i have awarded the points without good testing. When i type long text in the last EditText(opedt),it overlaps the button at the bottom. The text gets on top of the button. I want the text to stop just before reaching the button and scrolls.

Comment: The second relative layout is unneccessary

Comment: remove the second relative layout and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the Button

Comment: It looks like i have awarded the points without good testing. When i type long text in the last EditText,it overlaps the button at the bottom. The text gets on top of the button. I want the text to stop just before reaching the button and scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the RelativeLayout-wrapper from your button and add following attribute to your button: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to acheive your button always at bottom of the view and other elements will be at top in ordered format.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="gsie.beezlink.OpportunityActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/posterbtn"
        android:background="#008000"
        android:id="@+id/posterbtn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinteretxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/cinteretxt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cinteretspin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/optitretxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/optitretxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretspin"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/optitreedt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optitretxt"
        android:hint="@string/hintoptitre" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/optxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/optxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optitreedt"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opedt"
        android:hint="@string/hintpost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optxt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

if your content is getting out of view you can use scroll view

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_above:"@+id/posterbtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cinteretxt"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/cinteretxt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cinteretspin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/optitretxt"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/optitretxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cinteretspin"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/optitreedt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/optitretxt"
    android:hint="@string/hintoptitre"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/optxt"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/optxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/optitreedt"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/opedt"
    android:hint="@string/hintpost"
    android:layout_below="@+id/optxt"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/posterbtn"
        android:background="#008000"
        android:id="@+id/posterbtn"
         />
```